# How to get a ball in the nonvanishing locus of a polynomial in $\mathbb Z_p[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ canonically?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Suppose $f\in \mathbb Z_p[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, and consider $D(f):=\{(_1,…,_)∈ℤ^_:(_1,…,_)≠0\}\subset \mathbb Z_p^n$. How to calculate a radius $r$ from the datum of $f$ such that $D(f)$ contains a ball of radius $r$?

> Explanation: by "calculate" I mean representing a $r$ as a function of degree and coefficients of $f$.

Even when $n=1$ I only know such an $r$ can be the discriminant when $f$ is separable, and when $f$ is not separable I may need to replace $f$ by a maximal separable factor and this step is not natural for me (since I need a general formula depending only on degree and coefficients)

In higher dimensional cases I nave no idea.

Comment: What is $D(f)$?

Comment: @YCor Clearly $D(f) := \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{Z}_p^n : f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \neq 0\}$ here. But yes, it should have been stated explicitly.

Comment: @Richard It's not clear what you mean by “calculate”. Do you have a center $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\neq 0$ and are you trying to compute the radius around this center on which $f$ does not vanish, or are you trying to find center+radius? Because the naïve way I would find the center is by randomly drawing $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ until $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\neq 0$, and then I would translate this to the origin and use simple norm estimates to find a radius: this gives an algorithm, but I'm not sure that's what you're after.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting your question as follows: *given* $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ and *given* $\underline{x} := (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \neq 0$, you want to find $r>0$ such that $f\neq 0$ on $B(\underline{x}, r) := \{\underline{y}\in\mathbb{Z}_p^n : \|\underline{y}-\underline{x}\| \leq r\}$ where $\|\underline{z}\| := \max\{|z_1|,\ldots,|z_n|\}$ (and $|\cdot|$ refers to the $p$-adic absolute value).  The following answer seems a bit trivial, so I suspect I misunderstood your question, but here goes:

By translating, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $\underline{x} = 0$.  So now $f = c + (\text{non-constant terms})$ where $c = f(0) \neq 0$ is the constant coefficient and we are trying to find some $r$ such that $f$ does not vanish on $B(0,r)$.

Now any non-constant term in $f(\underline{z})$ is of the form $a z_1^{r_1}\cdots z_n^{r_n}$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ at least one $r_i$ nonzero.  Since the $z_i$ themselves lie in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $|\cdot|\leq 1$ on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, we have
$$|a z_1^{r_1}\cdots z_n^{r_n}| \leq |z_1|^{r_1}\cdots |z_n|^{r_n} \leq \max\{|z_1|,\ldots,|z_n|\} = \|\underline{z}\|$$
By the ultrametric inequality, $|f(\underline{z}) - c| \leq \|\underline{z}\|$.  In particular, if $\|\underline{z}\| < |c|$ then $f(\underline{z}) \neq 0$.  So any $r$ less than $|c|$ answers the question.

Comment: I have thought about this method. The defect of it is: $c$ is not computable (for computable I mean: write $c$ as a formula of degrees and coefficients of $f$ that works for all nonzero polynomials)

Comment: @Richard So you should probably edit the question again to clarify this meaning of “computable”. Because in the usual sense of “computable” as “algorithmic” (i.e., Church-Turing computable), this answer does provide an algorithm, viꝫ., enumerate $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in some order (this will suffice as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$) and for each $\underline{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ compute $f(\underline{x})$ and if it is nonzero return the radius as described. So what you want is some more restricted form of algorithm, e.g., without loops or even a polynomial of the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: I would see "computable" as more or less: given $k$ (and $n$)  and the polynomial $f$ given with coefficients that are given modulo $p^k\mathbf{Z}_p$ with at least one being nonzero modulo $p^k$ (and an algorithm to compute them modulo $p^\ell$ for$\ell\ge k$), output $m$ such that $D(f)$ contains a translate of $p^m\mathbf{Z}_p^n$.

Comment: @YCor That's also how I would have intepreted it, and this answer + my previous comment shows just that. But apparently OP wants something more, like an algorithm that does not loop, or one which just computes a polynomial of the coefficients of $f$.

Comment: Actually, could one expect a result depending only on the degree of $f$ (and the number $n$ of variables), regardless of the exact coefficients?

Comment: @YCor Good point! For given $n$ and degree, the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ having gcd 1 is compact so there should likely be a continuity argument giving a common $r>0$ for all.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Amazing! By induction I proved that : when $p^k>d$ ($d$ is degree), then $r=|p^k|$ is a common choice. Thank you two for valuable disgussions!